# PHP Email Function not working when to and from email is same

Tags: email

When  sent to and  send from email address same the php mail send function is not working but when i change to and from email address different then it works.

here is my sample code where now here i used exampleemail@example.com as demo email address.

can anybody face same problems? if yes please help me to sort out this issues.

```
<?php
echo "<h1> Simple Email Test Page</h1>";

$to      = 'exampleemail@example.com';
$subject = 'subject';
$message = 'Demo Message';
$headers = 'From: exampleemail@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: exampleemail@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "Mail Sent";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such issue where `TO` and `FROM` should not be same.

Well, I have tried your code on my hosting account and works fine(Got a mail by the same mail ID).

Check with your hosting provider.

You can Validate like this,

```
$retval = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   if( $retval == true )  
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }
```

Comment: when i used this email address programmer_heart@yahoo.com  and run code i did not got any email but when i changed to and from email different then this code works perfectly..  i put this code on different server and same result. Do you thunk its server issues?

Comment: Try with different mail id or check out in **SPAM** folder.

Comment: i tried different email id and spam folder as well . but not sending email when i use same to and from email

Comment: mail sent syccessfully but not getting any email. Its seems  like a strange problem :) its a simple function but when same to and from email its stop to send the email.

Comment: I had a sent mail to **programmer_heart@yahoo.com**. Have you got any mails by my name?